# Kibana DSL, aggregate on field where field has multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For example I have data like this:

```
{"product": "ProductA", "region": "Region 1", "sales": 25000}
{"product": "ProductA", "region": "Region 2", "sales": 30000}
{"product": "ProductA", "region": "Region 3", "sales": 45000}
{"product": "ProductB", "region": "Region 1", "sales": 25000}
{"product": "ProductB", "region": "Region 3", "sales": 30000}
{"product": "ProductB", "region": "Region 3", "sales": 45000}
```

And I would like to get all products where `product` is in `Region 1` and in `Region 2`.
So it should only return `ProductA`.

I've tried this but to no avail

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "metrics": {
      "terms":{
        "field": "product"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term" : { "region" : "Region 1" } },
        { "term" : { "region" : "Region 2" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bool query, Your query may look like this

```html
GET /saga/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"term": {
      "product": {
        "value": "ProductA"
      }
    }},
    {"term": {
      "region": {
        "value": "Region 1"
      }
    }}
  ]
  }
  }
}
```

And the curl form

```
curl -XGET "http://XXXXX/xxx/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {"bool": {"must": [    {"term": {      "product": {        "value": "ProductA"      }    }},    {"term": {      "region": {        "value": "Region 1"      }    }}  ]  }  }}'
```

Comment: But what if I want to find all products that adhere to specific rules?

Comment: This query basically matches all documents with _ProductA_ and _Region 1_, but I think @RnD wants a list of all product names where you have at least one document with that product name + _Region 1_ and one document with that product name + _Region 2_

Answer (score 0):

You can try **min_doc_count** supported by terms aggregation

```
 GET products/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "region.keyword": [
              "Region 1",
              "Region 2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "metrics": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 2 // <====== this should match with count of regions mentioned in the query part
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand, did you mean I should replace `should` with `must`? If that's the case then it sadly didn't work.

Comment: What you pointed out is the fact, that this query matches all products in either in Region 1 or in Region 2.
But using a _must_ or _filter_ wouldn't solve the problem, because the different regions per product are not in the same document.

Comment: my bad ... I updated my answer.. Please try now.

Comment: @Sahil Gupta, now it makes sense. Given the constraint, that the combination of _region_ and _product _in the documents is unique, this works pretty good. I like that.
However, if we have (as in the questions example - though I'm not sure if it was on purpose), `Product B` two times with `Region 3`, this gives us some trouble.
Searching for `Region 3` and `Region 4` with that query would return `Product B`, cause it has two docs matching `Region 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'll find a pure ES solution for that.

In your case, I would reconsider the structure of the data if possible - I would prefer something like:

```
{
  "product": "ProductA", 
  "regions": [
    {
      "name": "Region 1", 
      "sales": 25000
    },
    {
      "name": "Region 2", 
      "sales": 30000
    },
    {
      "name": "Region 3", 
      "sales": 45000
    }
  ]
}

{
  "product": "ProductB", 
  "regions": [
    {
      "name": "Region 1", 
      "sales": 25000
    },
    {
      "name": "Region 3", 
      "sales": 45000
    }
  ]
}
```

That makes it way easier to search for what you want.

EDIT: Added example query for my suggested data structure (not tested, but should work)

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "regions",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "regions.name": "Region 1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "regions",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "regions.name": "Region 2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```